# Django Can't Import from accounts.models

Tags: django

I have created a Django project and moved the entire project inside another directory

The file structure is like this

```
Project directory
    backend 
        accounts
            (Other app files)
            models.py
        example
            (Other app files)
            views.py
```

In example/views.py

```py
from accounts.models import User
# Unresolved reference: accounts
```

I don't know why I can't import the model

Comment: This is a warning being displayed by PyCharm, right? You need to mark the base directory of the project (which I assume is the `backend` folder?) as a "Sources Root", right-click the folder and then go to "Mark DIrectory as". Make sure there are `__init__.py` files in the app folders too

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for your help. Do you want to write an answer so I can mark it?